# How can I enter angles higher than 122.409 in a sine function in C

Tags: c

I was asked to make a sine function with creating my own library. I looked up for some hints on the internet and I made this code. But this function doesn't work when the angle is higher than 122.4099. Cannot figure how to deal with that. I'll post a part of my code from my library. (And I used Maclaurin and Taylor series.)

```
#include "stdio.h"
#define pi 3.141592


double power(double a, int b) // Imagined function 1
{
   double product=1;
   int i=0;
   if(b==0)
   {
      return 1;     
   }
   for(; i<b ; i++)
   {
      product = product * a;
   }
   return product;
}


int factorial(int a) // Imagined function 3
{
   if(a==0)
   {
      return 1;
   }
   return a * factorial(a-1);
}

double sinTrig(double angle) 
{
   double imgSet = 0;
   double sum = 0;
   int n = 0;
   double x;
   x = angle * pi/180;
   do
   {
       imgSet = power(-1,n) * power(x,2*n+1) / (double)factorial(2*n+1);
       sum = sum + imgSet;
       n++;
   }while(abs(imgSet) >= 0.00001);
   printf("\n The sine of %.3lf is :: sin(%.2lf) --> %.3lf", angle, angle, sum);
   return sum;
}
```

Comment: If you consider how the sine function works, you will see that you really only need to calculate it between 0 and pi/2 or 0 and 90 degrees.   Perhaps this will help you.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is test your `factorial` function. Write a program that prints the result of calling `factorial` with numbers from 1 to 21.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code

```
int factorial(int a) // Imagined function 3
{
   if(a==0)
   {
      return 1;
   }
   return a * factorial(a-1);
}
```

it is recursive function.

it generate stack overflow when `a` is big value.

when angle become large value, you calc big factorial.
remove recursive and use different way to calc factorial.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not actually on the code but on the maths behind it. In your sine function,

```
double sinTrig(double angle) 
{
   double imgSet = 0;
   double sum = 0;
   int n = 0;
   double x;
   x = angle * pi/180;
   do
   {
       imgSet = power(-1,n) * power(x,2*n+1) / (double)factorial(2*n+1);
       sum = sum + imgSet;
       n++;
   }while(abs(imgSet) >= 0.00001);
   printf("\n The sine of %.3lf is :: sin(%.2lf) --> %.3lf", angle, angle, sum);
   return sum;
}
```

you compute, as you well said, the MacLaurin series (also known as the Taylor series centered in 0). This means that your function approximates well the sine  function for angles close enough to 0, but the error becomes bigger when the angle is farther from 0.

Comment: This code is actually my homework, but I don't know a way to solve this other than the subjects we learned in class. So should I limit my sine function with the ranges -pi/2 and +pi/2 ? Because otherwise there will be lot more errors.

Comment: You can check what's your error as a function of the angle and determine the interval where the error is acceptable to you.

Comment: Other methods are possible but I guess really out of the scope for your hw. What you can do is define a few intervals (say 2) and have three Taylor series around the center of those intervals.